# Delay when update constant in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to update a constant using Redux in my React application. But there is a delay when my callback, `handleChange` is fired. It is logging the value before calling `setFormValues`. The react version is `^16.8.0` and  react-redux is `7.1.1`

#### Login.jsx

```
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({ email: ' ', password: ' ' });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const updatedValues = { password: '', email: e.target.value };
    setFormValues(updatedValues);
    console.log(formValues);
  };
```

Comment: useState looks like React hooks, completely unrelated to redux

Comment: this is because `setFormValues` sets the state and setting of state is asynchronous in React, and hence logging can happen before setting of the state is complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using React Hooks, which I think you are, you can use `useEffect` to log/manipulate the new value on each update, something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

...

const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({ email: ' ', password: ' ' });

const handleChange = (e) => {
  const updatedValues = { password: '', email: e.target.value };
  setFormValues(updatedValues);
};

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(formValues);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`formValues` is a simple variable that was set upon the call to `useState` on the first line.  It will not change during this render iteration.

When `handleChange` is called, the `console.log` uses the `formValues` from that iteration.  Only after the next time the component is rendered will `setState` return a new value, and `handleChange` be re-created with the updated value.